# Finding points in radius of each point in same GeoDataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have geoDataFrame:

```py
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[0, 'A', Point(10,12)], 
                       [1, 'B', Point(14,8)],
                       [2, 'C', Point(100,2)],
                       [3, 'D' ,Point(20,10)]], 
                      columns=['ID','Value','geometry'])
```

Is it possible to find points in a range of radius for example 10 for each point and add their "Value" and 'geometry' to GeoDataFrame so output would look like:

```py
['ID','Value','geometry','value_of_point_in_range_1','geometry_of_point_in_range_1','value_of_point_in_range_2','geometry_of_point_in_range_2' etc.]
```

Before i was finding nearest neighbor for each and after that was checking if  is it in range but i must find all of the points in radius and don't know what tool should i use.

Answer (score 0):

Although in your example the output will have a predictable amount of columns in the resulting dataframe, this not true in general. Therefore I would instead create a column in the dataframe that consists of a lists denoting the index/value/geometry of the nearby points.

In a small dataset like you provided, simple arithmetics in python will suffice. But for large datasets you will want to use a spatial tree to query the nearby points. I suggest to use scipy's KDTree like this:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[0, 'A', Point(10,12)],
                       [1, 'B', Point(14,8)],
                       [2, 'C', Point(100,2)],
                       [3, 'D' ,Point(20,10)]],
                      columns=['ID','Value','geometry'])

tree = KDTree(list(zip(df.geometry.x, df.geometry.y)))
pairs = tree.query_pairs(10)

df['ValueOfNearbyPoints'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

n = df.columns.get_loc("ValueOfNearbyPoints")
m = df.columns.get_loc("Value")
for (i, j) in pairs:
    df.iloc[i, n].append(df.iloc[j, m])
    df.iloc[j, n].append(df.iloc[i, m])
```

This yields the following dataframe:

```
   ID Value                   geometry ValueOfNearbyPoints
0   0     A  POINT (10.00000 12.00000)                 [B]
1   1     B   POINT (14.00000 8.00000)              [A, D]
2   2     C  POINT (100.00000 2.00000)                  []
3   3     D  POINT (20.00000 10.00000)                 [B]
```

To verify the results, you may find plotting the result usefull:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot()
df.plot(ax=ax)
for (i, j) in pairs:
    plt.plot([df.iloc[i].geometry.x, df.iloc[j].geometry.x],
             [df.iloc[i].geometry.y, df.iloc[j].geometry.y], "-r")
plt.show()
```

[image]